# Can't find the column splitter { \t } when i copied html table value inside Citrix Environment using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, clipboard, citrix

[image]Here is my code to copy value inside Citrix Environment. Using Clipboard but unfortunately I can't split the column. Please help to solve this. Thanks

*DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");*

```
foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
{
    string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

 if (pastedRowCells.Length <= 2)
 {
      string column1 = string.Empty;
      string column2 = string.Empty;        

    for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
    {
         switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                column1 = pastedRowCells[i].ToString();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                column2 = pastedRowCells[i].ToString();
                                break;
                        }
    }

    var Info = List<Info>();
    List.Add(new Info { columnInfo_1 = column1, columnInfo_2 = column2 });
 }
 else
 {
     MessageBox.Show("please paste exact number of columns");  break;
 }
}

public class Info
{
    public string columnInfo_1 {get; set;}
    public string columnInfo_2 {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Does the clipborad string has '\t\ in it?

Comment: Nope it only contains this string "\r\n"